# querystring missing value after postback

Tags: asp.net, webcam.js

I'm using webcam.js to get photos from a webcam using asp.net web form app. The problem is, I want to get the filename based on the "ID" querystring. But everytime I click "shoot" button, the querystring value is nothing.

Here's my complete HTML :

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"  CodeBehind="Coba.aspx.vb" Inherits="myWebcam.Coba" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Plugin/jquery.webcam.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Coba.aspx")%>';
        $(function (){
           $("#Camera").webcam({
                 width: 320,
                 height: 240,
                 mode: "save",
                 swffile: '<%=ResolveUrl("Plugin/jscam.swf")%>',
                 onTick: function () { },
                 onSave: function () {
                 },
                 onCapture: function () {
                     webcam.save(pageUrl);
                 },
                 debug: function () { },
                 onLoad: function () { }
             });
        });

        function Capture() {

            webcam.capture();

            return false;
        };
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
    <h2>Index</h2>

    <input type="button" value="Shoot!" onclick="Capture()" />
    <div id="Camera"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my asp.net codebehind :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class Coba
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public sID As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        sID = Request.QueryString("id")


        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Capture(Trim(sID))
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub Capture(ByVal mID As String)
        Dim stream = Request.InputStream
        Dim dump As String

        If stream.Length > 0 Then

            Using reader = New StreamReader(stream)
                dump = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using

            Dim path = Server.MapPath("~/" & Trim(mID) & ".jpg")
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, String_To_Bytes2(dump))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function String_To_Bytes2(strInput As String) As Byte()
        Dim numBytes As Integer = (strInput.Length) / 2
        Dim bytes As Byte() = New Byte(numBytes - 1) {}

        For x As Integer = 0 To numBytes - 1
            bytes(x) = Convert.ToByte(strInput.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)
        Next

        Return bytes
    End Function
End Class
```

The first time I run the page, I can get the "id" value from the querystring. The shoot button trigger the postback and run the "Capture" sub but the "id" querystring returns nothing.

Any solutions for this problem ?

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, you're not persisting the original `queryString` data for the subsequent `POST`back. You have a bunch of options to do that - from setting a `hidden` field, using `ViewState` , etc. - so you can send it (again) on a _subsequent_ request (whether it's a `POST`back or `GET`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code and I think there is a mistake concept. The plugin does not seem to append any QueryString. Your ID is always Nothing. I made debugging and found no trace of the addition ID in the QueryString.

The file name is an attribute that you assign yourself with your logic.
[Here is a complete example in which the ID is not recovered.](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Capture-Image-Photo-from-Web-Camera-Webcam-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Even in the [official page of the plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) there is no reference to the ID through Querystring.

---

Other things, you should not use the same page for the interface and saving process. The Pageload is always called, and you call `Capture(Trim(sID))` even when loads the interface.

I think you must change this line:

```
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Coba.aspx")%>';
```

In

```
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Coba_SaveImage.aspx")%>';
```

And all your codebehind go in the page `Coba_SaveImage.aspx`. In Page Load is not necessary the `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then` is always a postback.

Hope this help you.